# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

Estoy teniendo problemas para poder hacer funcionar esta pequeña aplicación en Spring Boot. La cual consiste en traer todos los "clientes" que hayan sido registrados entre 2 fechas.

Colocare aquí el código:

**Entidad**

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "clientes")
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "apellido")
    private String apellido;

    @Column(name = "fecha_de_registracion")
    private LocalDateTime fechaDeRegistracion;
}
```

**Repositorio**:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE fecha_de_registracion >= :desde AND 
fecha_de_registracion <= :hasta", nativeQuery = true)
List<Cliente> findClientesRegistrados(LocalDateTime desde, LocalDateTime hasta);
```

**Servicio**:

```
    @Transactional
    public List<Cliente> findClientesRegistrados(LocalDateTime desde, LocalDateTime hasta) 
     throws Exception {
        try {
            return clienteRepository.findClientesRegistrados(desde, hasta);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
```

**Controlador**:

```
@GetMapping("/buscarClientes/{desde}/{hasta}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getClientesRegistrados(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDateTime desde,
                                                    @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDateTime hasta) {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(clienteService.findClientesRegistrados(desde, hasta));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("{\"message\": \"Error. Please try again later.\"}");
        }
    }
```

Y estos son los registros que tengo hasta el momento en mi base de datos (trabajando con MySql):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El **endpoint** que intento en Postman es el siguiente:

http://localhost:9000/api/v1/clientes/buscarClientes/2021-06-03/2021-06-03

Al ejecutarlo me trae el error del título de esta pregunta. Seguramente estoy cometiendo un error bastante grave.

**Aclaración**: estoy trabajando en la entidad 'Cliente' con LocalDateTime porque luego tengo que trabajar con las horas y minutos que obtenga de los registros.

Desde ya muchas gracias por cualquier tipo de ayuda!

Comment: Quítale el ©DateTimeFormat o ponlr hh:mm en ceros  si funciona entonces debes utilizar otra forma para formaterlos

Comment: Y el Timezoneen el formato. En pocas palabras al formato que espera un LocalDateTime.  si más no recuerdo: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss y si t da error debes utilizar el parámetro iso